# how to make smarty's display function return to a variable

Tags: php, smarty

In smarty is it possible or is there any kind of function to render a template and return the result?

for example:

```
$rendered_content = $smarty->render("content.html")
```

Answer (score 18):

Yeah there is,

```
$rendered_content = $smarty->fetch("content.html");
```